# What time did TOM4656 land on 18 Jan 2020?

Tags: air-travel, austria, tui

Unclear how to use this forum correctly, but my question is simple. That said, I can't find the info anywhere. What time did TOM4656 land on 18 Jan 2020? Could someone find the info and give me a link or screen grab so that I can prove to my travel insurance that this flight was delayed about 7 hours and 20 minutes. WHen we finally landed I turned on my phone and of course received a message from Vodfone, and that was at 18:04 (instead of the planned arrival of 10:40). tx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find historical flight delay for TOM4656 on 18 Jan 2020](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152823/how-to-find-historical-flight-delay-for-tom4656-on-18-jan-2020)

Comment: How does one fish out the info needed? Please teach us. Official records are incorrect. We landed about 18:00 in Innsbruck after a diversion to Verona. TOM 4656 on 18 Jan 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Services like Flighaware or Flighradar may have some historical data.

BTW, I checked TOM4656 and according to fligtaware [it took off with 54 minute delay and landed on 12:20 on Jan 18](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/TOM4656/history/20200118/0745Z/EGKK/LOWI)

Comment: If you look at the map on FlightAware it looks like it diverted to Verona. That makes the claimed 7 hour delay quite plausible.

Comment: Indeed - it does not appear flighaware has any data after landing in Verona so it switched to some sort of estimate. Maybe some other service will track it better. Also, if you departed from Verona to Innsbruck on the same plane, try searching by plane number instead.